# Reload page via JavaScript with resending form information

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webforms, cross-browser, window.location

I use  `window.location.reload();` on my page.

But in Chrome it do not re-send form data.

Standart browser refresh, ask about resending.
FF and Opera works fine.

Is there some cross-browser solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (BAD ANSWER, SOLUTION BELOW)

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

**SOLUTION :**

Bad answer after research, sorry.
The only solution consists to create an hidden form with method post and simulate a submit on this form ;)

```
<form action="?" method="POST" style="display:none" id="myform">
<input type="text" name="mydata" value="myvalue" />
</form>
<script>
;$(function() {
  $('#myform').trigger('submit');
});
</script>
```